# Error on GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Above is my data and I got an error below when I ran the SQL.  Please help

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Query:

```
SELECT          
    LEFT(RTRIM(LEFT(IBDA.CUST_PO_I, 11)) + 
        LEFT(IBDA.CUST_PO_LINE_I, 3) + SPACE(14), 14) AS 'UNIQUE ID', 
    LEFT('' + Space(15), 15) AS 'PACK SLIP', 
    LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), IBDA.CALENDAR_INVC_D, 101) + Space(15), 15) AS 'DATE', 
    LEFT('vend' + Space(9), 9) AS 'VEND', 
    LEFT(Ltrim(Rtrim(IBDA.SHIP_Q)) + Space(12), 12) AS 'QUANTITY', 
    U.BASE_UOM AS 'UNIT OF MEASURE' 
FROM   
    AXE4321.AA.DBO.1TB IBDA 
LEFT JOIN 
    AXE1234.BB.DBO.2TB U ON IBDA.UOM_C = U.UOM_C 
WHERE  
    IBDA.CUST_I = '9377467' 
GROUP BY 
    'UNIQUE ID'
ORDER BY 
    [UNIQUE ID] DESC
```

Comment: you can't group by an alias

Comment: also when you group you need to account for all columns in the select that are not aggregated.

Comment: Why do you need a group by at all? No aggregation is being done.  `Distinct ` instead?

Comment: @KeithL I even try to GROUP BY LEFT(Rtrim(LEFT(IBDA.CUST_PO_I, 11)) + LEFT(IBDA.CUST_PO_LINE_I, 3) + Space(14), 14)   but got this error is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Can you post expected results? You're trying to group by UNIQUE ID, but you can't since it's an alias. You can CTE this query and GROUP BY, but you'll still need to aggregate the remaining columns.

Comment: @Simon  base on the data set I got I should get 1007508677460                  06/23/2017      vend      5000         EA
1007508677460                  07/07/2017      vend      10000        EA

Comment: @jp2631 then you need to SUM IBDA.SHIP_Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use a CTE:

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(SELECT          
LEFT(RTRIM(LEFT(IBDA.CUST_PO_I, 11)) + 
    LEFT(IBDA.CUST_PO_LINE_I, 3) + SPACE(14), 14) AS 'UNIQUE ID', 
LEFT('' + Space(15), 15) AS 'PACK SLIP', 
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), IBDA.CALENDAR_INVC_D, 101) + Space(15), 15) AS 'DATE', 
LEFT('vend' + Space(9), 9) AS 'VEND', 
LEFT(Ltrim(Rtrim(IBDA.SHIP_Q)) + Space(12), 12) AS 'QUANTITY', 
U.BASE_UOM AS 'UNIT OF MEASURE' 
FROM   
AXE4321.AA.DBO.1TB IBDA 
LEFT JOIN 
AXE1234.BB.DBO.2TB U ON IBDA.UOM_C = U.UOM_C 
WHERE  
IBDA.CUST_I = '9377467' 
ORDER BY 
[UNIQUE ID] DESC)

SELECT [UNIQUE ID], MAX([PACK SLIP]), DATE, VEND, SUM(QUANTITY), [UNIT OF MEASURE] --PACK SLIP seems like it's an empty column, so you could probably leave it out?
FROM CTE1
GROUP BY [UNIQUE ID], DATE, [UNIT OF MEASURE], VEND
```

I think this should do what you need, but this still requires modification. Please only use this as a reference and adjust the aggregations accordingly.